# SSRS: Update subscriptions to point to a copy of a report in a different folder

Tags: reporting-services, directory, clone, subscription, cloning

I'm cloning all our SSRS reports to another top-level folder (beneath the existing top-level folder). The cloned reports will be the same reports (pointing to a different shared data source, and a few reports with changes in the embedded dataset queries but same data output) and parameters. When we're done parallel testing the cloned reports against all the live reports, I'd like to be ready with a script (t sql or PS) that can easily point the existing subscriptions to the new, cloned reports and delete the old reports.

Sounds simple, but my t-sql approach in the past when migrating SSRS to a new instance has not been 100% when updating the existing subscriptions.

I looked at potentially using sp_update_schedule, but it doesn't contain a reportid parameter, so doesn't look like the solution.

BTW: Using SSRS 2019

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be very simple. Using SSMS, run the following queries against your ReportServer database:

1. Retrieve your old and new ReportID's. This query should result in (at least) 2 records. Use the "Path" field to identify which is your source vs. target report. Use the values in the "ItemID" field for step 2:

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog]
> WHERE [Name] = 'Employee Commissions' --Report name
> ```

2. Update all your subscriptions for this report with the new ReportID:

> ```
> UPDATE [ReportServer].[dbo].[Subscriptions]
> SET Report_OID = 'F74D29B0-4C20-4934-BB75-2CE63972C526' --new ItemID (from previous query)
> WHERE Report_OID = '54D0E73C-A936-40D3-A7BB-24C9E5B80CC5' --old ItemtID (from previous query)
> ```

That's it!